# In unity editor, point light has not brightness

Tags: unity-game-engine

it's very simple scene, I use builtin 3d Cube, and put point light, but point light has no any brightness

[image]

I guess it's because clear gi cache or change Lighting window settings, how to restore to default point light behaviour

my unity version

```
Version 2017.4.16f1 (7f7bdd1ef02b) Personal
Wed, 14 Nov 2018 21:49:01 GMT
Branch: 2017.4/staging
```

Comment: Why not use intensity?

Comment: @ThomasHilbert I just confused, why point light is not default behaviour(default behaviour should like lantern)

Comment: Intensity is the setting that effectively controls the brightness of point lights in Unity. Why it's called thus, I don't know. But it's got nothing to do with your environment, it's called Intensity on my system, too.

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution, in point light inspector, change "Render Mode" from "Auto" to "Important"

[image]

Comment: Well sort of not really. `Auto` should be used whenever possible, but the number of lights that will be "on" is dependent on the brightness of other nearby lights and the current Quality Settings. `Important` causes the light to always be rendered at per-pixel quality and should be used only for key effects. You should check your quality settings, as changing to a higher quality (the Editor can be set to any of the listed quality settings) may also cause the light to turn "on."